# How to check subsequent elements of string in python using iterators?

Tags: python, string, parsing, iterator

I have a sentence that I want to parse to check for some conditions:

> a) If there is a period and it is followed by a whitespace followed by a lowercase letter
>
> b) If there is a period internal to a sequence of letters with no adjacent whitespace (i.e. www.abc.com)
>
> c) If there is a period followed by a whitespace followed by an uppercase letter and preceded by a short list of titles (i.e. Mr., Dr. Mrs.)

Currently I am iterating through the string (line) and using the *next()* function to see whether the next character is a space or lowercase, etc. And then I just loop through the line. But how would I check to see what the *next, next* character would be? And how would I find the previous ones?

```
line = "This is line.1 www.abc.com. Mr."

t = iter(line)
b = next(t)

for i in line[:len(line)-1]:
    a = next(t)
    if i == "." and (a.isdigit()): #for example, this checks to see if the     value after the period is a number
         print("True")
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: sounds like you might want to use regex.

Comment: I'd suggest checking out Python's [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) documentation and an online playground like [Regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: is it possible to still implement it without regex?

Answer (score 1):

**Regular expressions** is what you want.

Since your going to check for a pattern in a string, you can make use of the python's builtin support for regular expressions through `re` library.

Example:

```
#To check if there is a period internal to a sequence of letters with no adjacent whitespace 
import re
str = 'www.google.com'
pattern = '.*\..*'
obj = re.compile(pattern)
if obj.search(str):
    print "Pattern matched"
```

Similarly generate patterns for the conditions you want to check in your string.

```
#If there is a period and it is followed by a whitespace followed by a lowercase letter
regex = '.*\. [a-z].*'
```

You can generate and test your regular expressions online using [this](https://regex101.com) simple tool

Read more extensively about `re` library [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple next operations to get more data

```
line = "This is line.1 www.abc.com. Mr."

t = iter(line)
b = next(t)

for i in line[:len(line)-1]:
    a = next(t)
    c = next(t)
    if i == "." and (a.isdigit()): #for example, this checks to see if the     value after the period is a number
         print("True")
```

You can get previous ones by saving your iterations to a temporary list

Comment: but if I add that line then the iterator will advance and the next time I come into the loop it will be further ahead than I want to. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct, thats why i also suggest saving your iterations in a temporary list